# Tabbed form and validation.

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm creating a tabbed form with validation, and there is one thing I don't understand how to do: when I hit the submit button, and there is a validation error in some field, the form is not submitted - but if the field is in an hidden tab (a non focused one), there is no error message displayed either.

Is there am easy way to switch to the tab with errors, or to inhibith focusing on following tabs until all errors in current one had been cleared?

I'm new to all the React, JSX and modern JS development, please do not be too much concise! :)

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. I'll investigate and let you know. However, if you can create a repository or a codepen showcasing the problem, please open an issue on our repository with a link to it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I reproduced the problem and opened an issue on our repository. I'll let you know how it goes.

In the mean time, one way to mitigate this issue would be to create a [custom saga](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#customsagas). You'll need some knowledge about [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) though.

The idea would be to:

- catch failed validations actions from redux-form (`SET_SUBMIT_FAILED`)
- trigger a custom notification with an error message indicating the field and the tab where the error occurred. Unfortunately, you'll have to check the fields names to know for which resource the error occurred.

Comment: Link to the issue: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/960

Comment: And here the pull request fixing it: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/pull/962. Please comment on it if needed :)

Comment: The pull request has been merged. You can either use the `master` branch directly or wait for the next minor version: `1.2.3`