# Form Validation for tabs in ReactJs using form-validator

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, tabs, material-ui

Have gone through some Q&A and this seems the close match [Tabbed form and validation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823301/tabbed-form-and-validation) to my issue. However, it does not solve my problem.

I'm using [react-material-ui-form-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-form-validator), where if you have multiple inputs within the **ValidatorForm** and you try to *submit*, it shows you errors and doesn't allow form submission if there are any errors.

Then, I separated the inputs into two parts and used [Material-UI tabs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs) within the **ValidatorForm**. **Now on submit it only shows the errors on the tab that is open, but not on the tab that is hidden**. One way to check was if some form data is **required**, I can check the state on submission and do something like don't submit and update the label of tab with an exclamation icon. But, that won't show the error fields.

But, I am looking for something which can make it simple without doing more checks on submit handler, rather validators can act as they act for one paged form.

Here is the [CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/textvalidator-required-tabbed-xwg7g?file=/src/App.js) for your reference. If you have any solutions, kindly fork your changes in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, technically is not possible to validate a `TextValidator` in `Tab` that is not the current `Tab` selected (because element on that `Tab` are not loaded on DOM).

BUT

we could do something. Basically, every time the `ValidatorForm` validate elements in form, calls `submit()` function. So the idea is: every time we change Tab, we can call this `submit()` to validate elements on Tab.

So, at first, create a ref for form:

```
<ValidatorForm
   ref={(ref) => { this.form = ref; }}
  ...
```

Then, on Tab change, we can call `this.form.submit()` in this way:

```
handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => {
   this.setState({ value: newValue });
   this.form.submit();
};
```

So far so good. I tried and it doesn't work :( Better, it works but only if you click 2 times on the same `Tab`. Why? Beacause the `Tab` has a lazy loading. So to remove this lazy loading we have to remove the condition `value === index` on `TabPanel` return function. Then I removed and now it works :)

But we can do even better. As long as submit button is not clicked, form should be not validated. So we can add an additional boolean to the state (default `false`) and when user clicks submit button we set this boolean to true:

```
<Button
   onClick={() => {
      this.form.submit();
      this.setState({ submitted: true });
   }}
>
  Submit
</Button>
```

And we add a condition to `handleTabChange` function:

```
handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => {
    this.setState({ value: newValue });
    if (this.state.submitted) this.form.submit();
  };
```

So, until button is not pressed, the form stills not validated. If user clicks button, form will be validated and, every time user changes Tab, `TextValidator`s, if contain an invalid value, will show the error.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/textvalidator-required-tabbed-forked-mqpu5?file=/src/App.js) your codesandbox modified.

Comment: Thanks! That's well explained for a better understanding.
However, @Giovanni Esposito talking about DOM, what if instead of display property "hidden" we do "none"? I tried that out and it worked, however there are warnings for forwardRefs in the tabs.

Comment: Resolved: Submit button should call form.submit rather than default submit.  So, I am not using the additional boolean for the state. :) [ForkedBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/textvalidator-required-tabbed-forked-t3bwn?file=/src/App.js)